# How do I add optional dependencies through pipfile?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, dependency-management, pipenv

I know I can do this is with regular pip:

```
pip install wtforms[email]
```

But I want to do this in my pipfile for pipenv

```
wtforms[email] = "*"
```

Which doesn't seem to work. I get this error:

```
Found invalid character in key name: '['. Try quoting the key name.
```

Is this possible through the pipfile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do: `pipenv install wtforms[email]`.

And you should also be able to do:

```
wtforms = {version = "*", extras = ["email"]}
```

I don't use `Pipenv` anymore, so I cannot test it, but it should work.

**Note:**

iin zsh shell I had to add quotes like `pipenv install "wtforms[email]"` .

Comment: explicitly adding it to the pipfile worked but the regular install did not.

Comment: Indeed, it seems like extras declared this way in the `Pipfile` will not actually be installed by `pipenv` when installing using `Pipfile.lock` ("regular install"). See the corresponding issue: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4407

Comment: @JakubKukul Looks like that issue has been [resolved](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed+archived%3Afalse+reason%3Acompleted) in the meantime.

Comment: In zsh shell I had to add quotes like `pipenv install "wtforms[email]"` .